# Auto-start livestream in video-js player

Tags: video.js, live-streaming

I have built a livestream server for our church that is pushing the live feed to a video-js player on a page which I can then embed in our main website.  This is working fine except I would like the stream to start playing automatically once it goes live (so if people are sitting on our site waiting for the live stream, they don't have to keep refreshing to get it to start playing).

I have seen mention of writing into the code for the player to keep querying the server every so many seconds and then start automatically, but I'm unsure how this gets written into the page.

Current code for live.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <script src='https://bacstream.live/videojs/video.js'></script> 
    <script
    src="https://bacstream.live/videojs/videojs-http-streaming.js"></script> <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>LiveStream</title> <link href="https://bacstream.live/videojs/video-js.min.css" 
    rel="stylesheet"> <!-- <link
    href="https://bacstream.live/videojs/videojs-sublime-skin.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> --> <!-- 
    <link
    href="https://bacstream.live/videojs/videojs-sublime-skin.css" rel="stylesheet"> --> <!-- <link
    href="https://bacstream.live/videojs/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet"> --> <!-- <link
    href="https://bacstream.live/videojs/videojs-skin-twitchy.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 
    --> </head> <body>
    <center> <video-js id="live_stream" class="video-js vjs-fluid vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play- 
   centered" controls
   autoplay preload="auto" autoplay="true" width="auto" height="auto" poster="https://thechurchco- 
   production.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/sites/2101/2020/06/Static-stream-page.png"> <source
    src="https://bacstream.live/live/stream/index.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL">
<p class='vjs-no-js'>
  To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that
  <a href='https://videojs.com/html5-video-support/' target='_blank'>supports HTML5 video</a>
</p> </video-js>

<script>
var player = videojs('live_stream', {errorDisplay: false});
    player.play();
  </script> </center> </body> </html>
```